# how to store data optimally for use in PySpark on google cloud

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I will be using PySpark to run stuff (regressions, ML, etc.) on a sizable structured numerical dataset (>1TB). Currently the data is in CSV format on google cloud storage. Is it optimal to convert the data into some other format (Parquet, etc.) to speed up reading into Spark or will read speed be about the same keeping it in csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the data to Parquet should give you a decent speedup. Not only will the files be smaller through the encoding & compression codecs Parquet applies but also Spark can create more efficient computation graphs when using Parquet as the input format. In the case of Parquet, PySpark can load the metadata and schema of the Parquet file at the beginning of the computation and use this metadata/schema to build a more efficient computation graph.

The schema will tell PySpark already the datatypes contained in the columns and thus more optimized routines with the correct types can be used whereas in CSV you actually would read string values and then convert them later to their correct binary type. As Parquet is a columnar format, columns not needed in the computation are not even loaded from the storage. Also the metadata will tell Spark a bit about the distribution of the data, thus the scheduler can more easily distribute the load among all workers.